# Can't get URLs to work on Django Apache EC2

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, deployment, django, mod-wsgi

This is my first time trying to setup a webserver with Django. I've been banging my head against the wall in trying to set this up for a while now and I can't seem to find any resources that explains this in a newbie formatted step by step manner.

I've installed and setup apache and mod_wsgi on my EC2 instance. How do I map the URLs of my app set in my urls.py file to apache? Locally, I can get my app to work my entering `127.0.0.1:8000/flickr/photousers` by running it on the Django development server. I'm trying to be able to get this to work on my public dns as `http://ec2-122-248-194-176.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/flickr/photouser` with apache and mod_wsgi.

When I restart my Apache server, I also get this error but with OK status
`[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *.80 -- ignoring`

Below lists the relevant snippets

**django.wsgi file**

```
import os,sys

apache_configuration = os.path.dirname(__file__)
project = os.path.dirname(apache_configuration)
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)
sys.path.append(/home/djangotest/flickr)
#sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'flickr.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**httpd.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
    DocumentRoot /home/djangotest/flickr
    ServerName ec2-122-248-194-176.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
    ErrorLog /home/djangotest/flickr/logs/apache_error.log
    CustomLog /home/djangotest/flickr/logs/apache_access.log combined
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/djangotest/flickr/apache/django.wsgi

    <Directory /home/djangotest/flickr/media>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/djangotest/flickr/apache>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    WSGIDaemonProcess ec2-122-248-194-176.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com user=djangotest processes=2 threads=25
    WSGIProcessGroup ec2-122-248-194-176.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

    Alias /media/ /home/djangotest/flickr/media/
</VirtualHost>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    (r'flickr/', include('flickrphotobrowser.urls')),
)
```

**urls.py (located in my app)**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from flickrphotobrowser.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('flickrphotobrowser.views',
        (r'^phototags/$', contenttags),
        (r'^photouser/$', contentuser),
)
```

**settings.py**

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'flickr.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__), 'templates'),
    #'home/nai/Projects/flickr/flickrphotobrowser/templates', # THIS IS FOR LOCAL ONLY
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'flickr.flickrphotobrowser',
)
```

Should I include any other snippets to help troubleshoot the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Couple of typos: the method names in the urls should be enclosed in quotations as well. So it should be `'contenttags'` and `'contentuser'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your httpd conf, change:

`<VirtualHost *.80>`

to

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

and restart Apache.

If that doesn't fix it, you could also try adding:

`sys.path.append('/home/djangotest')`

to your django.wsgi file.

Comment: Ok changing to `<VirtualHost *:80>` worked but now I'm getting an error `You don't have permission to access /flickr/photouser on this server.`(OMG A TYPO URGHHHHHHHHHH)

Comment: Don't worry, Steve has a mistake in his answer as well. The path supplied to sys.path.append should be quoted but ServerFault doesn't allow trivial edits for me. BTW, also make sure you have 'NameVirtualHost *:80' directive as well else name virtual hosts will not resolve properly.

Comment: @Graham Yes I saw that in the apache error logs! I also had a couple of permission issues which I fixed by changing the User and Group values. I was able to debug the rest of my problems after making the change he spotted.

Comment: You shouldn't normally be changing the User/Group of Apache itself. If using mod_wsgi you would be better off using daemon mode and have just the Python web application process run as different user/group y setting the user/group options to WSGIDaemonProcess. Only the WSGI script file then has to be readable/accessible to Apache user. Watch 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations'.